# Can't see new SSD when connected via internal SATA port

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, disk-utility, sata, system-information

I just bought a new Samsung SSD 830 and installed it my 13" MacBook Pro (Mid 2010) in the hard disk bay, replacing the drive that was there (I actually have a second drive in the optical drive's slot). Unfortunately, when I started up my computer (from the other drive I have), I can't see the SSD in System Information (formerly Profiler) or Disk Utility.

However, I see the drive fine when using a SATA-to-USB adapter and I also am able to see the old hard disk when it is connected via the internal SATA, so the internal wiring seems to be fine. Thus:

- HDD via USB: works
- SSD via USB: works
- HDD via internal SATA: works
- SSD via internal SATA: completely broken

Anyone have ideas for a fix?

Comment: I've tried resetting the PRAM but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the hard drive cable was broken. Replacing it fixed the problem completely.

[image: hard drive cable]

Comment: Hello Ben! Thank you for your Q/A. I have the similar problem. Is there a way to make sure, that the problem is in the internal SATA cable actually? Could you suggest how to obtain new replacement cable? And what could cause the damage to the internal cable? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows computer around you might try updating the firmware. Also I'm curious about what happens if you start the computer from the recovery disk. It's not the drive and it's not the cable. I suppose you can try really make sure the cable is seated well.  Alternatively, if it isn't too much of a hassle what happens when you take the extra drive in the optical bay out?