# MacBook Pro 13" Mid 2010 is not seeing internal SATA HDD

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, sata

I have a MacBook Pro 13" Mid 2010 that started to not see it's internal SATA HDD.

I can connect the HDD in question to the computer via SATA > USB adapter and it works fine (Mac can even boot from it that way).

What could be the problem and how do I diagnose and fix it properly?

I heard that it could be a problem with the internal SATA connector cable:
[Can't see new SSD when connected via internal SATA port](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52208/cant-see-new-ssd-when-connected-via-internal-sata-port), but is it possible to make sure that cable is a culprit without buying the replacement cable yet? What could cause damage to the cable in the first place?

Are there any other possible causes?

Comment: Engineer from local service center told me that it could be either cable or controller. I guess I will try to actually replace the cable myself. The connector part number is: `821-0814-A` if someone will look for it as well. I will give a feedback later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177615/84989) to a very similar problem affecting 2012 13" MBPs. It's highly unlikely it's your SATA controller - if your MacBook can read DVDs or CDs then it's definitely not your controller as it's the same one that the HDD/SSD will be connected to (Intel Series 7 Platform Controller Hub).

As for why these cables fail I've yet to get to the bottom of the issue, but the ones I've replaced have no visible mechanical damage whatsoever, and replacing them has restored full SATA functionality.

The question/answer I linked to has some information that may make your cable change slightly easier.

Comment: Thank you, for you answer. That was exactly the problem! After replacing the internal SATA cable it worked like a charm. Good idea about checking SATA controller functionality!